# how to test redirect in fuelphp

Tags: php, redirect, phpunit, fuelphp

I write a controller like this

```
public function action_submit()
{
$submit = Format::forge(json_decode($_POST["submit"]))->to_array();
Servicecode::add_code_request($submit);
Response::redirect('code/codedetail');
}
```

then i want to write phpunit to test it,

```
public function test_adminsubmit()
{
$Submit = array(...);
$_POST["Submit"] = json_encode(Submit);
$response = Request::forge('code/codeeditrequest/submit')
  ->set_method('POST')
  ->execute()
  ->response();
$this->assertContains('ode Detail', $response->body->__toString());
```

something wrong with this,it had insert the data in db,but when it run redirect,i can't redirect the page,so the test failed!WHy?What' wrong with this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my understanding, you can't write test like that.

Because `Response::redirect()` does not return any contents, but returns only HTTP header for redirection, and calls `exit()`. So your phpunit testing is aborted by the `exit()`.

To test code with `Response::redirect()`, you have to replace `Response::redirect()` method with test double somehow.